# Java Eclipse @Override error

Tags: java, eclipse, interface, overriding

I'm writing a Java class that's implementing an interface called Command, which contains the methods `isValid()` and `run()`, as follows:

```
public class DailyEnergy implements Command {

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(String command) {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public void run(String command) throws Exception {
  }
}
```

and here's the Command.java file:

```
public interface Command {

  public boolean isValid(String command);
  public void run(String command) throws Exception;
}
```

Within this class, I'm implementing the superclass methods `isValid()` and `run()`, and I want to add the `@Override` annotation, but Eclipse gives an error saying that "the methods must override superclass methods".

Even when I take out the methods and import them automatically with Eclipse, if I add the annotation, I get the error. If anyone can shed some light as to why I can't use the `@Override` annotation, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you copy and paste your code into the question?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The `@Override` annotation on interface implementations is supported since Java-6.  Are you possibly on Java-5?  Oracle [has acknowledged](http://blogs.oracle.com/ahe/entry/override_snafu) a mess-up in the [Java 6 docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html).  It has been [corrected in Java-7](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html).  See example below:

[image: Check compiler setting]

Comment: I'd check once again that the Project's and/or default Eclipse JDK is not set to JDK 5.

Comment: My goodness, you're right, that was the problem. I guess Eclipse defaults to JDK 5, since I never had Java 5 installed at any point.. Strange, because I swore I never had this problem before. But anyways, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Do you use JDK5?
As I have in mind is that , it's a bug in JDK5. @override is not allowed in implemention of interface in JDK5