# Eclipse @Override tag compilation error

Tags: eclipse, maven, gephi

I'm trying to use a [Gephi ToolKit Demo](https://github.com/gephi/gephi-toolkit-demos), it's a simple demo project that show how to use Gephi. It's a Maven project.

I get compilation error (`@Overide annotation`) in the all the classes of the `org.gephi.toolkit.demos.plugins.preview` package,

Eclipse propose to remove the `@Overide` annotation, but if I remove them I get nothing in result.

**More details:**
I'm trying to implement a listener mouse Interface in Gephi `PreviewMouseListener`, so I need to get mouse events notify when the user uses the mouse (click on graph nodes). So by implementing the `PreviewMouseListener` methods the @Overide annotation appear before the methods implementation, but Eclipse show compilation error.

I already checked the compiler compliance level in Eclipse (I found 1.7) as mentionned in this topics:

- [Why does Eclipse complain about @Override on interface methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987973/why-does-eclipse-complain-about-override-on-interface-methods)
- [Java Eclipse @Override error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220786/java-eclipse-override-error)

---

I tried to execute the same project using `Maven` command line in Windows and it compile and works good, and it doesn't show me any of those annotation errors.

If you need to see a quicly example just launch the `PreviewJFrame.java` class.

Any one have any idea how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Did you use correct JDK in your project? Did you checked compliance level of the project in the correct place?

Comment: did you try to run the maven build with the eclipse maven tooling? did you check the java build path of the project for the required library?

Comment: @IgorBljahhin for the JDK, yes under preferences->Java->Installed JREs and there I have jdk 1.7.0_79 and I try even using JDK 1.8, and for the compliance level I also check it under Java->Compiler and it's 1.7

Comment: @MatthiasSchmidt yes I already try it Maven Build (clean install as goals), and I had  'BUILD SUCCESS' , And yes I checked the required library and there is no missing library

Comment: The git repo doc says that this project is a demo for gephi in Neatbeans IDE. Maybe the pom configuration struggles with some Netbeans dependencies that can't be resolved in eclipse.